# Is it ok to use Huggingface with Pytorch lightning?

Tags: huggingface, pytorch-lightning

I have some Huggingface models that I'd like to finetune with PEFT LORA. I'd also like to use Pytorch Lightning Fabric for FSDP distributed training. However, I'm not sure if they'd be compatible with each other. Does anyone have experience using these two together?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Lightning Fabric just for FSDP. You can do so within the Hugging Face ecosystem through their Accelerate package. In the HF accelerate `config`, set the `distributed_type` to `FSDP` and set a `fsdp_config`.

Take a look at the entire documentation [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/accelerate/en/usage_guides/fsdp).

Answer (score 0):

I found there's currently an issue with lora with fsdp. Not sure how huggingface/lightning falls into play.

https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-llmstudio/issues/98